# filling in missing data based on another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, conditional-statements, missing-data, data-cleaning

I want to fill missing values in one column based on another column.
I have data with a column of US states and another with Cities. Some entries in the Cities are missing. I want to fill those Cities based on the mode city of the state they belong to. 
if the missing city is for DC the fill with Washington.

I tried this:

```
states = ['OH', 'WV', 'CA', 'FL', 'GA', 'SC', 'NE', 'IA', 'IL', 'MO', 'WI',
       'IN', 'MI', 'NJ', 'NY', 'CT', 'MA', 'RI', 'NH', 'PA', 'KY', 'MD',
       'VA', 'DC', 'DE', 'TX', 'WA', 'OR', 'AL', 'TN', 'NC', 'MN', 'KS',
       'OK', 'LA', 'CO', 'UT', 'AZ', 'NM', 'NV', 'VT', 'MS', 'AR', 'MT',
       'ME', 'ND', 'WY', 'ID', 'SD']
for state in states:
    freq_city = df.loc[lambda df: df['State'] == state]['City'].mode()[0]
    for df['State'] in states:
        if df['State'] == state:
            df['City'].fillna(freq_city,inplace=True)
```

however the if statement is ambiguous and rightly so. Just don't know what to do next

Comment: Can you post data? A minimum sample frame with desired results would help us help you. Off the top of my head, it should be something along the lines of: `df['City'] = df.groupby('State')['City'].transform(lambda grp: grp.value_counts().iloc[0])`. (can't use `mode` iirc)

Comment: `for df['State'] in states:` seems wrong, you're repurposing the Series to be used as an item in the for loop. Also what is the structure of `df`?

Comment: @BrianJoseph you weren't too far off, just had to modify your code to look like this:
df['City'] = df.groupby('State')['City'].transform(lambda grp: grp.fillna(grp.value_counts().index[0]))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick:

Depending on what do you mean by "missing city",

In case if it's `None`:

```py
df.loc[df["City"].isna(), "City"]=\
    df.groupby("State")["City"].apply(pd.Series.mode)\
    .loc[df.loc[df["City"].isna(), "State"]].to_list()
```

In case if it's empty string:

```py
df.loc[df["City"]=="", "City"]=\
    df.groupby("State")["City"].apply(pd.Series.mode)\
    .loc[df.loc[df["City"]=="", "State"]].to_list()
```

In case it's both:

```py
df.loc[df["City"].fillna("")=="", "City"]=\
    df.groupby("State")["City"].apply(pd.Series.mode)\
    .loc[df.loc[df["City"].fillna("")=="", "State"]].to_list()
```